# For what reason does this mockito code not compile?

Tags: java, mockito

I was trying to mock the `getTypeParameters()` method of the interface `javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement`.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html

It's possible to make it return an empty List, if it is written like this:

```java
TypeElement el = mock(TypeElement.class);
when(el.getTypeParameters())
    .thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
```

The following code should be equivalent, since it was generated by intellijs "extract variable" refactoring, but apparently it doesn't compile:

```java
TypeElement el = mock(TypeElement.class);
List<? extends TypeParameterElement> value = Collections.emptyList();
when(el.getTypeParameters()).thenReturn(value);
```

An even worse problem arises when trying to make it return a `singletonList`, because in that case, not even the "inlined" form compiles:

```java
TypeElement el = mock(TypeElement.class);
TypeParameterElement tpEl = mock(TypeParameterElement.class);
when(el.getTypeParameters())
    .thenReturn(Collections.<TypeParameterElement>singletonList(tpEl));
```

So what's the underlying problem here? Also, is there a workaround?

Comment: `Mockito.<List<? extends TypeParameterElement>>when(supplierElement.getTypeParameters())
    .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(tpEl));`

Comment: Or you can use `doReturn(Collections.singletonList(tpEl)).when(el).getTypeParameters();`.